# PhoneGap video record and upload to server

Tags: cordova

I have strange problem with PhoneGap, I am trying to record video from application and than upload it to server.

```
    app.initialize();

     $(function(){
      //capture callback
      var captureSuccess = function(mediaFiles) {
        var i, len;
        for(i = 0, len = mediaFiles.length; i < len; i += 1) {
          uploadFile(mediaFiles[i]);
        }
      };

      function uploadFile(mediaFiles) {
        var options = new FileUploadOptions();
        options.fileKey = 'file';
        options.fileName = mediaFiles.name;
        options.contentType = 'video/mp4';
        options.mimeType = mediaFiles.type;
        options.chunkedMode = true;

        var ft = new FileTransfer();
        var path = mediaFiles.fullPath;
        //var name = mediaFiles.name;

        ft.upload(path, 
          'http://domainName/~me/upload.php',
          function(result) { //success callback
            navigator.notification.alert('Path: ' + path +  ' bytesSent: ' + result.bytesSent + ' responseCode: ' + result.responseCode + ' response: ' + result.response, null, 'Upload Error');
            $("#infoMessage").html('Success!');
          },
          function(error) { //error callback
            navigator.notification.alert('Error uploading file ' + path + ', Error code: ' + error.code + ' Target: ' + error.target + ' http_status: ' + error.http_status + ' Body: ' + error.body + ' Exception: ' + error.exception.toString(), null, 'Upload Error');
            $("#infoMessage").html('Problem')
          },

          options);
      }

      // capture error callback
      var captureError = function(error) {
        navigator.notification.alert('Error code: ' + error.code, null, 'Capture Error');
      };

      //start video capture
      var accessCamera = function() {
        navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(captureSuccess, captureError, { limit:1 });
      };

                $("#cambtn").on('click', accessCamera);
```

Server side is working as it should I have tested it with Postman application.
Response that I get from PhoneGap application "Success callback" is: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtOjS.png)

Server side script is so basic for now:

```
$target_dir = "uploads/";
if(isset($_FILES['file'])) {
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target_file);
}
print_r($_FILES); //This line returns empty array when request is send by the application but it returns array with data when I test it with Postman. 
die();
```

Problem was due to the chunkedMode option. It has to be set to false.

Answer (score 0):

Your success callback function says 'Upload Error' if you scroll all the way to the right

```
        function(result) { //success callback
             navigator.notification.alert('Path: ' + path +  ' bytesSent: ' + result.bytesSent + ' responseCode: ' + result.responseCode + ' response: ' + result.response, null, 'Upload Error');
             $("#infoMessage").html('Success!');
```

Comment: That last parameter is just a title of popup notification as you can see on screenshot so, that is not problem at all.

Comment: Sorry misunderstood your question. I saw "Upload Error" on your image before I saw the comment in your code explaining the error. I would check the android monitor and also the server log. You can make the php write a log and troubleshoot it there as well. I am looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29099303/uploading-file-over-https-with-cordova-filetransfer and trying to see if it is possible that the success block gets called even if there is an error if the url is not whitelisted or something like that,

Comment: Also check for header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); in your php

Comment: When I add header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *); It is the same result. I also tried with setting last parameter to 'upload' function to 'true' (trustAllHosts for self-signed security certificates) but still no joy... :/

Comment: A couple of things to try. Try not including the contentType option. I don't see that in the documentation. Also try adjusting the mimeType. The correct one might be "video/mpeg" and you might set that instead of using mediaFiles.type, See if it works without that option. Also  on the server side I assume that isset($_FILES['file']) is returning false from the app. You want to verify that by returning some debug info to the app. Also try returning print_r($_SERVER) to see what is coming up in there.

Comment: It is really strange that when I try that same script with localhost (wamp) after changing max_upload_size and max_post_size in php.ini everything works as it should but I did all the same on server I'm just getting empty response... :/ print_r($_FILE) return empty array as you can see on screenshot.

I will try what you suggested now.

Comment: Problem was chunkedMode in my example it was set to true and it needs to be false...